# Where is source for tensorflow gym environments implementation

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, actor-critics

I need to implement custom `tensorflow` gym environment to use it with tf agents.

Is there a code on Github for "standard" gym environment? Eg cart pole

Please note this is tensorflow specific question not openAi

Comment: Do you mean something like [openai gym](https://github.com/openai/gym)?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to my comment:

OpenAI Gym provides a cartpole example:
[Cartpole.py](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py)

If you need any additonal information regarding gym, Cartpole integration or Actor-Critics I can highly recommend the following lectures:
[Reinforcement Learning @ FAU](https://cmutschler.de/rl)

Comment: No I meant tensorflow own `suit_gym` - it's similar to open ai gym but it has all the power and parallelism of tensorflow

Comment: Also I need code of an actual environment class not a sample how to use it. I need to implement my own environment so its easier by looking at a working environment code

Answer (score -1):

According to this tutorial:
https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/2_environments_tutorial

you either create python (OpenAi like) environment and then use tensorflow wrapper to make it more efficient (covered in the tutorial)

or

create pure tensorflow environment, code example here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/tf_agents/environments/tf_environment_test.py